# Generation of random numbers at no cost to the database

Tags: python, django, database

I will build a raffle site and it needs to support several simultaneous people. For this, any optimization is welcome.

Testing or verifying available numbers in the database can be a little damaging. As they are random numbers, I need to insert them with the certainty that they are not drawn to avoid repetitive queries.

One solution would be to store the undrawn numbers in some complementary file and faster than a database and after adding the numbers, update the file and remove the used numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand your question to be asking for suggestions on optimizing a raffle site that needs to support multiple people simultaneously. You are concerned about the performance impact of verifying available numbers in the database, and are looking for alternative solutions to avoid repetitive queries.

1. You could use a caching mechanism to store the undrawn numbers temporarily in memory, rather than continuously querying the database for available numbers. This can significantly reduce the database load and improve performance.
2. You could generate a pool of random numbers upfront and store them in a file or in memory, then select from this pool when needed. You would only need to generate new numbers once the pool is exhausted, reducing the frequency of database queries.
3. You could use a distributed or NoSQL database that can handle large volumes of simultaneous requests more efficiently than traditional relational databases. This can help ensure that the raffle site remains responsive even during periods of high traffic.

Comment: I thank you for your reply. Among the options, I was thinking about the second one. When creating the draw, define the maximum number of numbers and create 50-100 .txt files (they are faster) with unique numbers. With each request, I would take a file and block it with the fcntl lib so that another user does not have the same numbers, after taking it, I would modify the .txt file and release the file to another user. What do you think, dear colleague?

Comment: Using text files with unique numbers can be slow and may introduce race conditions when multiple users are accessing the same file. It may be better to use a database or in-memory data structure to store unique numbers instead. If you still want to use text files, you should implement a robust file locking strategy to prevent race conditions, and generate multiple sets of unique numbers upfront to reduce the likelihood of users requesting the same file simultaneously. Also, thanks for the upvote. I have an assignment to get at least two on an answer.

Comment: Could you tell me how and how to generate these numbers in memory, colleague? Thank you for answering even with the question closed!

Comment: Regarding .txt files, the fcntl lib blocks and only allows one user to have access to that file. Therefore I create 50 or 100 files for multiple simultaneous users. And the whole operation should last about 300ms.

Comment: Using Python's built-in uuid module: This module provides functions to generate unique identifiers (UUIDs) that are guaranteed to be unique across space and time. You can use the uuid.uuid4() function to generate a random UUID.

Using Python's built-in itertools module: The itertools.count() function returns an iterator that generates a sequence of unique numbers, starting from a given value. You can use this function to generate a sequence of unique numbers in memory.

Here's an example of using uuid module to generate unique identifiers:

Comment: import uuid

# generate a random UUID
unique_id = uuid.uuid4()
print(unique_id)

Comment: And here's an example of using itertools module to generate a sequence of unique numbers:

import itertools

# generate a sequence of unique numbers, starting from 1
unique_numbers = itertools.count(1)
for i in range(10):
    print(next(unique_numbers))

Comment: Sorry I cant do a code block with a comment

Comment: Can we chat on another network? If you want.

Comment: If you can and want to help me with this issue, which would be of great help, this is my nickname TON 618#5046 on Discord

Comment: The solution with uuid would be good, but numbers between 1 and 1 million are mandatory